# Extend the properties returned by a function?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm a JS beginner. I have defined a function on my Backbone model as follows.

```
myFunction: function () {
  return {
    firstAttr: this.model.get('value-attribute')
  };
}
```

It is available to me as `this.myFunction`.

From somewhere else in the code, I want to extend `this.myFunction` to return another attribute. In other words, I'd like it to return a dict with two attributes: `{ firstAttr: 'something', secondAttr: true }`.

How can I do this?

I've tried:

```
this.myFunction().secondAttr = true;
```

but I know that's the wrong thing to do.

Comment: Well, myFunction returns a new object each time so `this.myFunction().secondAttr` doesn't make a lot of sense as it would just be lost immediately. `var f = this.myFunction(); f.secondAttr = true;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your model prototype looks like

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    myFunction: function () {
        return {
            // I assume you work directly on a model
            // the principle would be the same with a wrapper object
            firstAttr: this.get('value-attribute')
        };
    }
});
```

you can either mask your method on a model by model basis like this:

```
var m = new MyModel({'value-attribute': 'attr, the first'});
console.log(m.myFunction());

m.myFunction = function () {
    var res = MyModel.prototype.myFunction.call(this);
    res.secondAttr = true;
    return res;
};
console.log(m.myFunction());
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/V8zt2/ for a demo

Or dynamically modify your prototype to alter all instances :

```
var f = MyModel.prototype.myFunction;
MyModel.prototype.myFunction = function () {
    var res = f.call(this);
    res.secondAttr = true;
    return res;
};

var m = new MyModel({'value-attribute': 'attr, the first'});
console.log(m.myFunction());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/V8zt2/1/

Answer (score 0):

How about modifying your `myFunction` to :

```
myFunction : function () {
    var i,
        obj = {};
    for (i=0; i< arguments.length;i++){
        obj['attribute'+(i+1)] = this.model.get(arguments[i]);
    }
  return obj;
}
```

This way you can send `keys` of `model`, that you want to be in the returned object as arguments to `myFunction`.